# Read Core Data base but Model lost

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I have a Core Data base on my iphone with data I don't want to lose.

I did a mistake in Xcode and lost xcdatamodel...

Now I don't know how to restore my data in a new model !

Is there a way to read a Core Data base in a "NSDictionnary" without a model ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to recover the data, you can open the sqlite file in "SQLite Database Browser 2.0"

Comment: I'd like to make it a programmatic way (I can't ask users to extract data with "SQLite Database Browser" and then import it in the application).